# Вывести массив без строк

Tags: javascript, массивы, методы

Нужно отфильтровать массив, не используя какие-либо методы массивов и строк. Не знаю, как можно так отфильтровать, чтобы не использовать push для массива. Без push в массиве отображаются не только числа

```js
    const nums = [];
    const arr = ['cat', 1, 6, 'dog'];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i] === 'number') {
            nums[i]=arr[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const nums=[]
const arr = ['cat', 1, 6, 'dog']
let index = 0

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arr[i] === 'number') {
        nums[index] = arr[i]
        index++
    }
}
console.log(nums)
```

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант:

```js
const nums = [];
const arr = ['cat', 1, 6, 'dog'];

for (const item of arr) {
  if (typeof item === 'number') nums[nums.length] = item;
}

console.log(nums);
```